# how to Inverse laplace transform of coth() function

Tags: matlab, maple

I have a function like this: `U = coth(s/100)/(s^3 + a*s + b)` and i use `ilaplce(U,s,t)` to find invers laplace transform, but matlab can not give me the answer.

```
>> syms t x s
>> U = coth(s/100)/(s^3 + s^2 + 1);
>> u = ilaplace(U,s,t)
u =
ilaplace(coth(s/100)/(s^3 + s^2 + 1), s, t)
```

i try doing inverse of another function of coth(), but i receive the same result.

```
>> K = coth(s);
>> k = ilaplace(K,s,t)
k =
ilaplace(coth(s), s, t)
>>
```

i try to do it with maple, but there is still no answer:

```
> with(inttrans);
> invlaplace(coth(s), s, t);
                          invlaplace(coth(s), s, t)
```

So what should i do ? thanks for answer !

Comment: have you considered that there is no analytic expression for that? I'd try Mathematica... (or wolfram alpha)

Comment: `InverseLaplaceTransform[Coth[s/100]/(s^3 + s^2 + 1), s, t]` in Mathematica 9 finds no solution as well.